# Localization add new language to list

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization

I am trying to localize my app but I'm stuck with adding a new language to my project.

I followed a tutorial but it said that you should click on the + button like in the image.
http://www.madmob.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Screen-shot-2011-05-04-at-10.11.01-PM.png

But I don't see these buttons. How can I add a new language to my Localizable.strings file?

Comment: how do you mean you don't see the `+` button on the image? the `+` button is on the image what you linked... I'm so confused.

Comment: + - for add / remove a localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the localization first in the "Localization" section of the "Info" tab for the project. Once added to the project, the new localization is available for the strings file.

Comment: I don't have a Localization section in the Info tab (latest Xcode version)

Comment: Select the project (the top-level item) in the Project Navigator. Then  select the PROJECT, not the TARGET. There should be an Info tab with a "Localizations" section.

Comment: @jordi12100: Did you find it? May I ask why you un-accepted the answer?